# ismember fails to find a number generated by bwlabel

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

Following this post by steve: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/27/using-ismember-with-the-output-of-regionprops/

I wanted to apply it on a very simple case. Here is the logical image that I have, it clearly has three objects:

[image]

This is the code I used :

```
[L_t,n_t] = bwlabel(logical_image);
iii = find(L_t == 2);
bbb = ismember(L_t,iii);
imshow(bbb);
```

But all I am getting in `bbb` is an empty matrix. i.e. a logical image the same size of the original but consisting entirely of `0`.

`n_t` shows 3 objects found. the max value of `L_t` is `3`. Then how come `ismember` fails to find 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `iii` is a list of indices (positions in `L_t` where `L_t == 2`), and `L_t` is a number from 1 to 3.  This is **not** the same as what they are doing in the original example:

```
idx = find((100 <= area_values) & (area_values <= 1000))
```

Here, `area_values` is a list taken from `regionprops` of the area of the different regions in your labelled image. It has the same length, `n`, as the number of regions (different values) in `L`.  e.g. if there are 10 areas in the image and areas 1, 3, and 7 have areas in the specified range the output of `idx` is `[1 3 7]`.

This then selects the parts of `L` where `L` is 1, 3, or 7:

```
bw2 = ismember(L, idx);
```

In your case, `iii` is a list of pixel indices, not their values. So none of those values are 1, 2 or 3 (even where you looked for the ones that were equal to 2), as those are the indices of the first three pixels of the image. Therefore none of the values in `L_t` match any of the values in `iii`.

If all you wanted was an image showing only the second object, then this is enough:

```
bbb = L_t==2;
imshow(bbb)
```